# How to change the downloadpath in InnoSetup?

Tags: inno-setup

I want to download and install the .net framework 4.5 with silent installation in innosetup,using below condition i will check whether .netframework 4.5 available or not, if not i will download from web using shellexec. here i attached the code.

```
function Framework45IsNotInstalled: Boolean;
var
 bVer4x5: Boolean;
 bSuccess: Boolean;
 iInstalled: Cardinal;
 strVersion: String;
 iPos: Cardinal;
 ErrorCode: Integer;
begin
 Result := True;
 bVer4x5 := False;

 bSuccess := RegQueryDWordValue(HKLM, 'Software\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full', 'Install', iInstalled);
 if (1 = iInstalled) AND (True = bSuccess) then
  begin
    bSuccess := RegQueryStringValue(HKLM, 'Software\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full', 'Version', strVersion);
    if (True = bSuccess) then
     Begin
        iPos := Pos('4.5.', strVersion);
        if (0 < iPos) then bVer4x5 := True;

     End
  end;

 if (True = bVer4x5) then begin
    Result := False;

end;
ShellExec('', 'http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=225702','{app}', '', SW_SHOWNORMAL, ewNoWait, ErrorCode);

end;
```

Now my doubt is,while starting the download it opens the web browser, and it doesn't install the .net framework automatically, user need to install manually,i want innosetup to install automatically after download is happening, installation should happen in silent manner.Can i get any idea to achieve this task??

Comment: Try to adopt e.g. the [`InnoTools Downloader`](http://www.sherlocksoftware.org/page.php?id=50) for .NET setup downloading.

Answer (score 1):

When using `ShellExec()` to tell the default browser to download something, then you have no control over what it does.
If you want to be able to run it afterwards, you will need to use an integrated downloader like [InnoTools Downloader](http://www.sherlocksoftware.org/page.php?id=50), or just ask the user to run it the install.